# ImportError at /admin/ in Django 1.9.4

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I updated my Django Version to 1.9.4 and now I get an Import Error

```
No module named views
```

when I try to accessthe Admin-URL.

`django.contrib.admin` is included in Installed_Apps in settings.py

How to fix this error?

The rest of the Django project is working fine.

Error log:

> [26/Mar/2016 12:54:02] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 114684
>   Internal Server Error: /admin/
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 265, in wrapper
>       return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
>       response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
>       response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 234, in inner
>       if request.path == reverse('admin:logout', current_app=self.name):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 568, in reverse
>       app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 360, in app_dict
>       self._populate()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 316, in _populate
>       for name in pattern.reverse_dict:
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 346, in reverse_dict
>       self._populate()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 334, in _populate
>       lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback, (bits, p_pattern, pattern.default_args))
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 255, in callback
>       self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 100, in wrapper
>       result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 115, in get_callable
>       mod = import_module(mod_name)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name)
>   ImportError: No module named views

mysite/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

mysite/blog/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^view/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)', 'views.view_post', name='view_blog_post'),
   url(r'^category/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)', 'views.view_category', name='view_blog_category'),
]
```

mysite/blog/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from blog.models import Post, Category

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['posted']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

Comment: Please show your urls.py

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found the solution.

The mistake was in the `mysite/blog/urls.py`

I just removed the quotes in

`url(r'^view/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)', views.view_post, name='view_blog_post'),`